# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 404 - Axios, React

Tags: reactjs

Its throwing an error in the details page saying Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 404. Could someone help me what i'm doing wrong. I'm basically trying to get the data to be printed when the user clicks on movielist component and it directs to details page and displays all the content.

Whats wrong with api call using Axios?

Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Title from '../Title/Title';
import MovieList from '../MovieList/MovieList';
import axios from 'axios';

 class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            allMovies : [],
            crimeMovies : [],
            dramaMovies : [],
            actionMovies : []
        }
    }
     componentDidMount (){
        const token = 'Bearer Wookie2019';
         axios.get('https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies',{
            headers: {
              'Authorization': token
            }
          }).then(response => {
            const { data: {movies} } = response;
            this.setState({
              allMovies: movies,
              crimeMovies: movies.filter(movies => movies.genres === 'Crime'),
              dramaMovies: movies.filter(movies => movies.genres === 'Drama'),
              actionMovies: movies.filter(movies => movies.genres === 'Action'),
          });
         console.log(response);
       });


     }

    render() {

        const movies = this.state.allMovies.map(movie => {
            return <MovieList key = {movie.id} title = {movie.title} poster = {movie.poster} genres = { movie.genres} />
        })
        const criMovies = this.state.crimeMovies.map(movie => {
            return <MovieList key = {movie.id} title = {movie.title} poster = {movie.poster} genres = { movie.genres} />
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <Title/>
                {movies}
                {criMovies}
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

MovieList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MovieList extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { history, movie } = this.props;
        if(history) history.push(`/Details/${this.props.slug}`);
    }
        render () {
            return (

                <div onClick = { this.handleClick}>
                    <div className="container-fluid movie-app">
                    <h5>{this.props.genres}</h5>
                        <div className =" row d-flex align-items-center mt-4 mb-4">

                            <div className ="image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3">
                            <Link  to={`/Details/:${this.props.slug}`}>
                                    <img src={this.props.poster} alt='movie' className="imgpos"></img>
                                </Link>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default withRouter(MovieList);
```

Details.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Title from '../Title/Title';
import './Details.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Notfound from "../Notfound/Notfound";

class Details extends Component {

    state = {
        movie : []
    }
     componentDidMount (){
         const  { match } = this.props;

         const slug = match.params.slug;

        const token = 'Bearer Wookie2019';
         axios.get(`https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies/${slug}`,{
            headers: {
              'Authorization': token
            }
          }).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                movies: response.data.movies
            })
         });


     }

    render () {

        const  { movie } = this.state;

        if (!movie){
            <Notfound/>
        }
        return (

            <div>
                <Title/>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className ="col-md-4">
                            <img src={movie.poster} alt='movie' className="detimg"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <div className="detailsTitle">
                                <strong>Title: </strong> {movie.title}
                            </div>
                            <div className="detailsInfo">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div className="detailsCast">
                                <strong>
                                    Cast:
                                </strong>
                               
                            </div>
                            <p className="detailsDesc">
                             <strong> Movie Description: </strong>
                             {movie.overview}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: is this `slug` has the value when the API request is called? Also, what does your network tab in the browser shows? Does it shows correct data in `Headers` section?

Comment: Are you getting any values back in your "Home.js" for movies? anything in "allMovies", "crimeMovies", "dramaMovies" or "actionMovies?

Comment: @AbhayDesai yes i'm getting the values from home.js for "allmovies". "allMovies" does include various categories such as drama, action. but when i try filter them i'm not getting any values.

Comment: i'm taking slug as an id https://wookie.codesubmit.io/movies to display all the content of the movie that is being clicked. And when i click on the movie component it goes to http://localhost:3000/Details/undefined @emkarachchi

Comment: then that is an issue, why your filter is not filtering records and giving you movies for different genres? Are you sure that your movies records has a field called "genres" on which you are trying to filter your records?

Comment: I see `this.props.slug` in your MovieList component is `undefined` . you have to pass the prop slug in the `render` method of your `Home` component.

Comment: @AbhayDesai Yes there's a field in api called as genres.

Comment: You need to add slug as `<MovieList key = {movie.id} title = {movie.title} poster = {movie.poster} genres = { movie.genres}  slug={ADD_YOUR_SLUG_VALUE_HERE}/>`

Comment: @emkarachchi Thanks its leading to that page but the content and image is not displaying

Comment: Did you added the slug value and now you have a value like `localhost:3000/Details/YOUR_SLUG_VALUE` instead of `localhost:3000/Details/undefined`

Comment: Yes i did add the slug value to the movie list <MovieList key = {movie.id} title = {movie.title} poster = {movie.poster} genres = { movie.genres} slug ={movie.slug}/> and its leading to the link http://localhost:3000/Details/the-dark-knight-2008 but i'm unable to get values there? @emkarachchi

Comment: Can you update the question with your router code? Do you have it defined like `<Route path='/Details:slug' component={Details} />`

Comment: <Route path="/Details/:slug" component = { Details }/> this is how i have defined the route @emkarachchi i sense its something i'm missing in details.js

Comment: What is the output from  `console.log(match.params)` in `componentDidMount` in `Details.js`?

Comment: Its showing the output in the console.log for the slug. but its not printing. My apologies i'm new to React.

Comment: @emkarachchi
Its showing the slug: "the-dark-knight-2008" in the console.log. but its not printing. My apologies i'm new to React.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not printing" ?

Comment: @emkarachchi when i click on the movie comopnent it leads to localhost:3000/Details/the-dark-knight-2008 In that detail page its not showing anything on the page, no images or the content